# initial directions in geodesic equations

Tags: differential-geometry, geodesics

in solving geodesic equations, how do you find components of initial tangent vectors (or initial direction) given initial values for t, r, theta and phi?

im reading this article on using the geodesicgeometry package in mathematica and at some point it says in there:
suppose we want to find the geodesic originating at ($t=0, r= 4m, \theta = \phi = 0 $) with initial direction $2\partial_{t} + \partial_{r} $....

my question is: where did the expression $2\partial_{t} + \partial_{r} $ come from? and what does it mean?

Comment: Usually it makes sense to calculate the geodesic curve between two points of the ambient space. Positing that one knows the direction of the geodesic infinitesimally close to the first fixed point seems to be unnatural from a physical point of view. So my guess would be that this is a trick that facilitates the computation in Mathematica.

Comment: Which article ?

Comment: @DinosaurEgg how is it physical to know where something is going to end up, as opposed to knowing its velocity?

Answer (score 2):

You do not find it, it should be thought of as additional data that you should provide.

There are two main ways by which you can determine a geodesic: by giving two points in spacetime the geodesic must cross, or by giving the initial point and the initial tangent vector of the trajectory. Just as in newtonian mechanics a particle departing from the same point would trace different trajectories if its initial velocity is changed, so is the case in solving geodesic equations. So the expression for the initial direction you are talking about is not derived from anything; it's a choice. And what it means is simply that your initial tangent vector has a component in the time direction and another in the radial direction -- that is, a radial trajectory with no angular displacement initially.